# How to build dll in Eclipse without dependency of Cygwin1.dll

Tags: dll, build, dependencies, cygwin

I have developed my own dll in Eclipse using cygwin compiler. Currently, I have to load cygwin1.dll and call cygwin_dll_init method in cygwin1.dll to load my own dll.

Is there any way to build my own dll which shouldn't depend on cygwin1.dll?

Comment: can you specify and add what functions you're using that's related to cygwin? If those functions are provided by cygwin1.dll, it maybe hard to separate unless you somehow statically link it with your program. I'm not sure the license would allow for that however.

Comment: @Victor : It is hard to find the functions related to cygwin. So I need some configuration type of things that can make cygwin1.dll as independent of my own dll.

Answer (score 2):

You should switch from the gcc cygwin compiler to mingw, which is a gcc build that uses the C runtime from MS instead of its own emulation layer, like cygwin.
http://www.mingw.org/

how to use mingw with eclipse

[clicky](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Eclipse,_CDT_&_MingW_Setup_Guide)

Comment: @ dema80 : I can't switch over to mingw. Since I am using some functions releated to cygwin.

Comment: if you use functions related to cygwin, you have to live with the cygwin dll then.. The cygwin code has to sit somewhere :)